# Error while loading fmu by pyfmi.load_fmu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, fmi

I want to load a 'fmu' in Linux by pyfmi.load_fmu, but I get a error.

error1 in env1:

> Could not find GLIMDA.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/user/Documents/hdh/paper/ling_min_du.py", line 12, in 
>           model = pyfmi.load_fmu(fmu_path)
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 7899, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 2558, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1.**init**
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 1167, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase.**init**
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 45, in pyfmi.fmi.encode
>       TypeError: latin_1_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes

error in env2:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "ling_min_du.py", line 26, in 
>           model = pyfmi.load_fmu(fmu_path)
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 7898, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 2553, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1.**init**
>         File "src/pyfmi/fmi.pyx", line 1225, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase.**init**
>       pyfmi.fmi.FMUException: The FMU contains no binary for this platform.

env1:
I have installed the FMILibrary and import pyfmi successfully.
pip list:

```
      Package              Version  
    -------------------- ---------
    absl-py              0.7.1    
    Assimulo             3.0      
    astor                0.7.1    
    astroid              2.0.4    
    certifi              2019.6.16
    cycler               0.10.0   
    Cython               0.29.11  
    gast                 0.2.2    
    google-pasta         0.1.7    
    grpcio               1.22.0   
    h5py                 2.9.0    
    Keras-Applications   1.0.8    
    Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0    
    kiwisolver           1.1.0    
    lazy-object-proxy    1.4.1    
    lxml                 4.2.3    
    Markdown             3.1.1    
    matplotlib           2.2.2    
    numpy                1.16.4   
    pandas               0.23.4   
    Pillow               6.1.0    
    pip                  19.1.1   
    protobuf             3.8.0    
    PyFMI                2.5      
    pyparsing            2.4.0    
    python-dateutil      2.8.0    
    pytz                 2019.1   
    scikit-learn         0.20.0   
    scipy                1.3.0    
    setuptools           41.0.1   
    sip                  4.19.8   
    six                  1.12.0   
    tensorboard          1.14.0   
    tensorflow           1.14.0   
    tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0rc1
    termcolor            1.1.0    
    tornado              6.0.3    
    typed-ast            1.4.0    
    Werkzeug             0.15.4   
    wheel                0.32.2   
    wrapt                1.11.2
```

env2:
      I try to reinstall pyfmi by conda install, get a new error.
      pip list:

```
      Package         Version  
    --------------- ---------
    Assimulo        3.0      
    certifi         2019.6.16
    cycler          0.10.0   
    kiwisolver      1.1.0    
    lxml            4.3.4    
    matplotlib      3.1.0    
    numpy           1.16.4   
    pandas          0.24.2   
    pip             19.1.1   
    PyFMI           2.5.3    
    pyparsing       2.4.0    
    python-dateutil 2.8.0    
    pytz            2019.1   
    scipy           1.3.0    
    setuptools      41.0.1   
    six             1.12.0   
    tornado         6.0.3    
    wheel           0.33.4
```

```
import numpy as np
import pyfmi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmu_path = './fmu/FeedSystem_Examples_current_2.fmu'

start_time = 0.
final_time = 10.
sample_period = 0.001
simulation_steps = int((final_time - start_time) / sample_period)

model = pyfmi.load_fmu(fmu_path)
opts = model.simulate_options()
opts["ncp"] = simulation_steps
result = model.simulate(start_time=start_time, final_time=final_time, options=opts)

result = np.array(result["massWithStopAndFriction.s"]).reshape(-1, )

plt.figure()
plt.plot(result)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in env1 is due to a bug in PyFMI that is fixed in later versions of PyFMI (>=2.5.1)

The problem in env2 is that the FMU you are using do not contain the necessary binaries for the platform you are currently on. So regenerate the FMU (or ask the person where you got the FMU) with support for your current platform.